# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

file_get_contents gives this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=&client_secret=fe9f106b05f6ab737a67ccc94a782767&grant_type=client_credentials) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/filevanc/public_html/scripts/cpa/facebookvirallink.php on line 25
```

Here is line 25:

```
 $cred = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$appID&client_secret=$secret&grant_type=client_credentials");
```

I have also tried using a different approach to file_get_contents like so:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($domain,false,$context);
```

But this gives the same error.

Any advice on what else I can try?

Comment: The error is "bad request". That means the request is made, the server is processing it and arrives at the conclusion that it's not what it expected. You're sending a malformed request. Take a second look at the documentation for the API you're trying to access, and see if you're making a correct request or you're missing something.

Comment: @rid ok i understood, I deleted my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I did a little reading around and for anyone else who stumbles upon this. I used:' $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $requstdomain); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);'

And say what was causing the bad request. cURL has much better error reporting. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The client_id is empty in the call that is actually made, so it looks like your $appID variable has no value when used on line 25.